# Query on keys using expressions on redis and python

Tags: python, regex, redis

I have created one `hashset` using Python

```
import redis

redisClient = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379,db=0)
redisClient.hset("orders", "test1", "One")
redisClient.hset("orders", "test2", "Two")
redisClient.hset("orders", "abc1", "Two")
```

Now i would like to create query on the above generated `hashset` using various regular expressions to find the value based on some regular expression

> eg. find all values having  key matching as test.

Answer (score 0):

we can search using  hscan like this iterates over the hashset and based on the key of your hashset you can define differen parameters to search .

eg . my hashset key was like this  :

SSDT_2018-12-09T07:15:00|SEDT_2018-11-07T15:45:00|DWST_10/5/11 11:00|DWEDT_10/5/11 15:00|STID_25|OTIA_7|OSSI_1|DAID_10|CID_10|TCID_0|DID_1|ENO_0|ISD_FALSE

Not to filter values based on various patterns ,hscan can be used  like this  :

```
for order in redisClient.hscan_iter('orders', match=('*SSDT_2018-12-09T07:15:00*' or  '*FALSE' or '*CID_10*' or '*DAID_10*' ) ):
    print(order)
```